# Algorithm Factorial with two Arguments Function(n,m)

Tags: algorithm, mergesort

I am solving my Homework and unable to understand the problem please explain me the question so that i can solve for the solution.
The question is.

- Write a recursive function to compute the factorial using divide and
  conquer as in Merge-Sort. That is, assuming n  m, write a function
  Factorial(n,m) that computes n(n − 1)(n − 2) · · · (m + 1)m. The
  top-level call will be Factorial(n, 1).

Help me in Understanding the problem with following things:-

1. Why there are two arguments in factorial function?
2. How will the execute like i understand that for the given problem if i choose n=8, m=5 the execution will be like 8x7x6x5 only? Is that correct?
3. As far as i have read for the methods of solving the factorial. Iterative and Recursion. They only take an input of 1 number i.e. Factorial(n) to compute for the value of n. ? Explain me how to start.

**

Comment: Factorial(n, m) actually is n!/m!. And also, it wants you to understand that 20!/1! = 20!/10! * 10!/1! which also is Factorial(20, 1) = Factorial(20, 11) * Factorial(10, 1)

Comment: @ShaneHsu Actually Factorial(n,m) = n!/(m-1)!

Comment: Ya, you're absolutely right, sorry lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like merge sort:

```
function EvalFact(x, y) {
    return x * y;
}

function Factorial(m, n) {
    z = m;
    If (m != n) {
        p = floor((n - m) / 2); //(integer division)
        x = Factorial(m, m + p);
        y = Factorial(m + p + 1, n);
        z = EvalFact(x, y);
    } 
    return z;
}
```

Call Factorial(1,n)

Comment: +1 This matches the question's requirements when it says *"Write a recursive function to compute the factorial using divide and conquer as in Merge-Sort."*

Comment: What is the if-statement for? Both branches do the same.

Comment: @LutzL we need the "if" in order to separate the cases where m==n (I return m) and m!=n (I call factorial and return the product exactly like merge sort).

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan: I was referring to the inner if statement that checks if m-n is even but is doing the same thing anyway.

Comment: @lutzL you are right. For some reason I needed it, but it does not necessary and I forgot removing. Thank you for point this.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword is "divide and conquer". So that you can compute 20! by dividing the task into the products from 1 to 10 and secondly from 11 to 20, and then the product from 11 to 20 into products 11..15 and 16..20. etc.

Why you would do that is not that clear since the number of multiplications does not change. You may be able to balance bit lengths of factors in "big integer" scenarios.

Comment: I guess this is just an exercise. See the solution below

Comment: Yes, recursion is at the heart of "divide-and-conquer".

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, Factorial(n,m) should not be visible to user...

In general, for writing some recursive logic, you need to pass some additional state to later method calls... but you can always hide this method from users view, and call from Factorial method with one parameter

Comment: Can you guys please provide me some rough view; that how should i start.

Comment: SO is not for homework problems, but well here is the algorithm ;) http://forum.projecteuler.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=1471

Answer (score 1):

if i get it right... written in javaScript this recursive function could be something like this...

**version 1** (top level call is Factorial(n,1) ):

```
function Factorial(n,m) {
  if (m>1) {
    return Factorial(n, 1) / Factorial(m-1, 1);
  } else {
    if (n>1) {
      return n * Factorial(n-1, 1);
    } else {
      return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

but this - simpler **version 2** will also work:

```
function Factorial(n,m) {
  if (n>m) {
    return n * Factorial(n-1, m);
  } else {
    return m;
  }
}
```

**version 3** divide and conquer:

```
function factorial(n, m) {
  if (n == m) {
    return n;
  } else {
    if (m > n) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return factorial(n, Math.round((n+m)/2) ) * factorial( Math.round((n+m)/2)-1 , m);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dear @webdev-Dan I guess this not what the exercise is asking (divide and conquer) See the solution below.

Comment: @DanielTheRocketMan I just added divide and conquer - you're right it is in question - but i don't see the benefits of this algorithm as it takes more steps than version 2 i wrote.

Comment: you are also right. The only benefit is to explore the idea of merge sort that sometimes are difficult for students. I liked since I never thought about evaluating factorial like this before. However it is not more efficient as you claimed.